# Magento: Disabled admin configuration option

Tags: php, magento

I have created an admin configuration option through system.xml. But, I would like this should disabled and cannot be editable by admin users.

How it is possible?

Comment: If you have created acl in your module, then you can restrict access to particular configuration to the user by using ROLES and USERS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the field as disabled, try this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10460/showing-system-configuration-form-field-as-disabled

If you don't want to show the field at all, use ACL or just configure it like this in system.xml:
    0
    0
    0

Comment: Thank you for the solution; I will try this.